# Application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b)

Tags: c++, windows, qt, visual-c++

I am unable to debug the application, always getting ***0xc000007b***
I am using the following configuration:
QT 5.3.0
MSVC 2012
64bit Compilation.
I added the following libs to my linking:
Qt5Core.lib;Qt5Gui.lib;Qt5Widgets.lib;
Optionally I tried to add the following as well (out of despair):
qtmain.lib;libEGL.lib;libGLESv2.lib;

I have the following dlls in the path:
Qt5Core.dll Qt5Gui.dll Qt5Widgets.dll 
Again (out of despair) added the following dlls to the path:
qwindows.dll qminimal.dll libEGL.dll libGLESv2.dll

And I verified using dependancy walker that all of the dlls are 64 bit

This is the code:

```
void Bar(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    try {
        QApplication app(argc, argv);
    } catch (...) {
    }
}
```

And when I remark the main line

```
void Bar(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    try {
        //QApplication app(argc, argv);
    } catch (...) {
    }
}
```

I don't get any errors, and by errors I mean, of course, the application won't even start...

The main is:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Bar(argc, reinterpret_cast< char ** >(argv));
}
```

Here is the error as displayed in the output:

'QtTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\workspace\plugin\TrdParty64\Qt5Core.dll'. Module was built without symbols.

'QtTest.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\workspace\plugin\TrdParty64\Qt5Core.dll'

'QtTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\workspace\plugin\TrdParty64\Qt5Core.dll'. Module was built without symbols.

'QtTest.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\workspace\plugin\TrdParty64\Qt5Core.dll'

The program '[8936] QtTest.exe' has exited with code -1073741701 (0xc000007b).

Comment: what error do you get? compile error or run-time?

Comment: What errors exactly don't you get then? Can you show more than just "unable to start correctly? How are you trying to run this example? Also, please show all the code you have for the application. If it is too big, strive for an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: please also show us main()

Comment: Show us the whole textual error. `0xc000007b` could mean many things.

Comment: are the msvc runtime dlls in path?

Comment: They must be in the path, since I am able to run and debug the application once I remark the problematic line from the code

Answer (score 1):

qwindows.dll (and qminimal.dll) need to be in platforms/ relative to your executable (or in your path)

Maybe that is the problem here?

Also make sure that all dll's are the right Qt version (for example 5.5.0 vs 5.5.1)